# Две проблемы с JS калькулятором

Tags: javascript

есть пара проблем с калькулятором на JS, и я не знаю, как их решить:

1. Не знаю, как сделать одну кнопку для скобок
2. Не знаю, как сделать кнопку "+/-" (положительное число в отрицательное, и обратно).

Со скобками пробовал:

```
if (elements[i].innerHTML === "()") {
    screen.innerHTML += "(";
}
if (screen.innerHTML.includes("(")) {
    screen.innerHTML += ")";
}
```

Но у меня ничего не вышло.

С отрицательным числом пробовал:

```
if (elements[i].innerHTML === "+/–") {
    screen.innerHTML = screen.innerHTML * (-1);
}
```

Получившийся результат как бы работает, но стоит ввести отрицательное число второй раз, или сделать второе число отрицательным, то выдаёт "NaN". Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить эти две проблемы. Ссылка на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/IcEWaRRiOr/a2vdz7rp/13/)

Comment: Есть мнение, что в screen.innerHTML не число, если сначала нажали на минус, а потом добавили цифру. А если там не число, то умножение НЕчисла на (-1) даёт в результате NaN.

Comment: Опять же, в порядке бреда, если нажатие на другие кнопки не выполняет сразу никаких вычислений, то и +/-  должно добавлять или убирать минус в начале строки, всё остальное оборачивая скобками. Например, если в строке было 3 * 5, то в результате должно получиться -(3 * 5). То есть знак должен смениться на противоположный у всего значения, что есть в параграфе. Но покамест у вас вычисление на "=" не очень работает.